how to use service principal to upload custom policy to b2c
I have a registered app with secrete created.

I can get the access token using above client id, tenant id and secret value.
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default" https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token

Permissions have been setup.

I can upload custom policy without issue.
az rest --method put --headers "Content-Type=application/xml" "Authorization=Bearer xxxxx " --url 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/trustFramework/policies/xxx/$value' --body "@xxx.xml"

Now I change to use service-principal login to get the token, using same above client id, tenant id and secret value.
az login --service-principal --username $client_id --password $client_secret --tenant $tenant_id

# access_token=$(az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph --query accessToken -o tsv | tr -d '\r')

I can get back a access token. But when I tried to upload file, it gives this error.
Forbidden({"error":{"code":"AADB2C","message":"'3b3bf757-6233-4fd2-9ed0-df708b80d59d' is not an Azure AD B2C directory. Access to this Api can only be made for an Azure AD B2C directory.",
Did I login correctly when using service principal? Why it doesn't work to upload?

Try to compare access tokens on jwt.io. I think that the second token has different audience and maybe the scope.

The error occurs if you use normal Azure AD tenant service principal to get token and upload custom policy to B2C tenant.
Initially, I too got same error when I ran below script by passing normal Azure AD service principal credentials and tenant ID.
tenant_id="AADtenantId"
client_id="AADappID"
client_secret="AADsecret"

policy_file="C:\custompolicy\B2C_1A_ChangePhoneNumber.xml"

az login --service-principal --username $client_id --password $client_secret --tenant $tenant_id --allow-no-subscriptions

access_token=$(az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph --query accessToken -o tsv | tr -d '\r')

az rest --method put \
  --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/trustFramework/policies/B2C_1A_ChangePhoneNumber/\$value" \
  --headers "Content-Type=application/xml" "Authorization=Bearer $access_token" \
  --body "@$policy_file" 

Response:

To resolve the error, make sure to pass Azure AD B2C service principal credentials and tenant ID.

You can also pass your B2C tenant name as value for --tenant. In my case, I ran below script by passing Azure AD B2C tenant name and got response like this:
tenant_name="b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com"
#tenant_id="AADB2C_tenantID"

client_id="AADB2C_appId"
client_secret="AADB2C_secret"

policy_file="C:\custompolicy\B2C_1A_ChangePhoneNumber.xml"

az login --service-principal --username $client_id --password $client_secret --tenant $tenant_name --allow-no-subscriptions

access_token=$(az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph --query accessToken -o tsv | tr -d '\r')

az rest --method put \
  --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/trustFramework/policies/B2C_1A_ChangePhoneNumber/\$value" \
  --headers "Content-Type=application/xml" "Authorization=Bearer $access_token" \
  --body "@$policy_file"

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where custom policy uploaded successfully like this:

In your case, cross-check whether you are passing Azure AD B2C service principal credentials and tenant ID or not in your second request. Otherwise, pass your B2C tenant name as value for --tenant as I suggested above.

Thank you! --tenant $tenant_name --allow-no-subscriptions makes it work!

Glad to know it worked :)
